# Can't connect to the wifi

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

I have ubuntu 14.04 and when  I want to connect to the wifi my network manager found nothing and when I use this command

> sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

It can find my essid wifi and when I use this command to connect

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "sample"
```

Nothing happen and I can't connect neither my ifconfig command show this

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:0e:03:49  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:131573 (131.5 KB)  TX bytes:131573 (131.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ed:b9:fa:1f:3b  
          inet6 addr: fe80::aed:b9ff:fefa:1f3b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:29
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17
```

My wifi device is broadcome :

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
```

This is the text file of that script for my wifi information

[Text File Contain My Wireless info](http://txt.do/kbkq)

What should I do to connect to the wifi??

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: here is that ext file you wanted http://txt.do/kbkq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem just edit one file:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and just change the value of false to true

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

And solved

Answer (score 0):

First change the wpa/wpa2 encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Second set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Third go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Fourth shutdown your computer and unplug your usb wireless device so your internal wireless can work then reboot, if it does not connect then post a new file without usb wireless plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Using the kernel driver, you won't be able to connect unless your 20ft within range of the router.

If you want your usb wireless device to work (rtl8192cu) properly, you may want to install the proprietary driver with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms

git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1 

cd rt8192cu

sudo make dkms
```

And use the following to load the driver

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

Notice this module uses "8192cu" instead of "rtl8192cu" to load.

Finally,update your /etc/modules folder accordingly with this command:

```
echo '8192cu' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

With this driver you get full 300Mb/s instead of 150 and there is full encryption suport as well. Not only that but the range is **at least** 10 times better than the kernel driver and **no more dropped signal**.

https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu

Comment: But that didn't work now I have wifi drive and when I use iwconfig to connect to wifi it just connect but don't get ip form dhcp I should set ip myself what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: This is the one you asked about in this question `03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n` and we can only have one question per question not two, so for the other device you need to start a new question. The answer by mchid does not be long here because it is not answering the question you asked.

Comment: @WildMan While the OP _mentions_ the Broadcom device, the question is "can't connect to wifi". This certainly solves the connection issue asked about and then some because this driver with this device is like night and day. **(Bit Rate:300 Mb/s Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****)** how many wireless devices can you say that for in Ubuntu. Also, this driver with the rtl8192cu card that she's using (and currently connected to the AP with) according to this http://txt.do/kbkq information. Thanks for the heads up but Im familiar with this device (took me weeks to figure it out)

Comment: @WildMan It's really a good card. I picked one up from dlink at officedpt for less than $20 and it turned out to be the best card I have. You have to run `echo "2001 330d" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id` to get it recognized, however.

Comment: Any way my problem didn't solve I still have my wlan0 but can't connect to the wifi

Comment: Did you do what was in my answer? If so we still need to see new file from script i am on my cell at the moment.